# How does TFS use the Affects & Affected By link types?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

When creating new bugs & tasks, I frequently find myself wishing I had a "caused by" link type that expresses a causal relationship between some work and the new ticket. This particular wording is missing, but in its absence I always consider using Affects & Affected By. However, I can't find any guidance about how these link types are to be used, and if the system utilizes them for any particular purposes, like reports or queries or something.

To that end, I have two questions:

- How should I express this causal relationship? The nondescript, directionless "related to" from 2005/2008?
- What are Affects & Affected By actually used for?

Comment: We use TFS on a daily basis and AFAIK most link types don't have any impact on the TFS system (only work items have an impact). The only link type having 'some' effect is the parent-child relation ship (even if you set a task in work, the corresponding UserStory isn't set to 'InProgress' automatically -> no effect by link in TFS, only the workload for the sprint gets updated nothing else). Mostly the link types are there to ensure the people working with TFS understand the purpose of the link, nothing else AFAIK.

Comment: Well, kind of--most of them mean something, somewhere. changeset links are used for build; parent/child are used in queries & reports; predecessor/successor are used when integrating with MS Project; tests/tested by/test result/test case are used by MTM; model link is used with Architecture modeling projects; Related is there only as legacy from before directed graphs were introduced in VS 2010; storyboard is for the new sharepoint/powerpoint stuff. Affects & Affected By are really the only ones that are totally mysterious to me.

Comment: Very interesting. Didn't know TFS links maybe have such an impact. At least we didn't recognize after more then a year of development :) or :( .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the main work item link types, depending if the link is between a WorkItem and another WorkItem or between a WorkItem and a Test Case.

**WorkItem -> WorkItem**

- Parent/Child
- Predecessor/Successor
- Related

**WorkItem -> Test Case**

- Tests/Tested By
- Affects/Affected By
- Shared Step/Test Case

You can also create custom link types!

Ref: [Link work items and objects to support traceability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/dd293534.aspx)